# Active Record Relation Showing Up in Query String Instead of ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to figure out as to why I get an active record relation showing up in my query string instead of an ID number. It seems as though an active record relation is getting passed through, but I'm not entirely sure why. This is what my query string looks like at the moment:

```
http://localhost:3000/schools/2/courses/%23%3CSchool::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fac99bfafe8%3E/posts/new
```

Here is all the relevant code:

Routes:

```
resources :schools do
resources :courses do
  resources :posts
end
```

end

Courses Controller:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @courses = Course.all
    end
    def show
        @course = Course.find(params[:id])
        @school = School.where({id: @course[:school_id]})
    end
end
```

Posts Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @post = Post.new
        @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
        @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    end
end
```

Courses show.html.erb file:

```
<h1><%= @course.name %></h1>

<p><%= link_to "create new post", new_school_course_post_path(@course,@school)%></p>
```

models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school
    has_many :user_course
    has_many :users, :through => :user_course
    has_many :posts
    has_many :is_tutors
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school
    belongs_to :course
    belongs_to :user
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_school
    has_many :users, :through => :user_school
    has_many :courses
    has_many :posts 
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, thanks. This helps from a refactoring standpoint but it seems I still have issues. I was thinking I have an error in my models or routes, but I'm just not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code in

courses_controller.rb

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @courses = Course.all
  end

  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    @school = School.where(id: @course.school_id)
  end

end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks, but it looks like the problem still exists. Isn't @course[:school_id] the same thing as @course.school_id ? What would be the difference in this context?

Comment: NVM, that worked! thanks a ton, I didn't actually think it would make a difference but there is a difference between the two. thanks